# AngularJS routing doesn't work with Django and CoffeScript

Tags: django, angularjs, coffeescript

I am quite new to AngularJS and CoffeeScript and I am following this tutorial about using AngularJS with Django: https://thinkster.io/brewer/angular-django-tutorial/. However I have a problem with angular routing. It seems to be totally ignored by Django. Below there are my files with routing and the controller used in this routing.

**myproject.routes.coffee**

```
    app = angular.module 'myproject.routes', []

    app.config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
        $routeProvider.when('/register',
            controller: 'RegisterController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            templateUrl: '/static/templates/authentication/register.html'
        ).otherwise '/'
    ]
```

**register.controller.coffee*

```
app = angular.module 'myproject.authentication.controllers', []

app.controller 'RegisterController', ['$location', '$scope', 'Authentication', ($location, $scope, Authentication) ->
    $scope.register = ->
        Authentication.register email, password, username
]
```

When I try to open localhost:8000/register Django simply loads emergency catch-all route defined in urls.py. I hope that the problem is somewhere in these files, but if not, I can upload whatever you need.

I would be really grateful for your help!

Comment: because your path would be `localhost:8000/#/register`. Will use hash unless you set html5mode and do rewrites on server. Read the docs

Comment: Also must be an old tutorial , `ngRoute` was moved out of core a long time ago so need to include as dependency

Comment: @charlietfl `localhost:8000/#/register` doesn't work either. However, in myproject.config.coffee I have `$locationProvider.html5 true` and `$locationProvider.hashPrefix '!'` and `localhost:8000/!#/register` doesn't work either. I think that its not such an old tutorial because its git repo was updated a month ago. And additionally in the file **myproject.coffee** I have `angular.module 'myproject.routes', ['ngRoute']` and still the same...

Comment: if you turn on html5 mode server has to be set to rewrite back to app entry point.

Comment: it doesn't work even if html5 mode is set to false

Comment: because hashbang is backwards ... try localhost:8000/#!/register with html5=false. This assumes your index file is in root also

Comment: Even with these settings nothing has changed.

Comment: are errors thrown in console? WHat does happen?

Comment: There are no errors in the console, I just have normal index page,as it is set in Django urls.py `url(r'^.*$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),`. It seems like django is totally ignoring or omitting angular routing.

Comment: I don't know django at all or pyhton much. the way it needs to work though is everything except say a directory like api (for data) and some assets needs to get returned to the root path. Everything after the root is done in browser routing

Comment: Everything seems to be done like this...

Comment: But...if you use the hash, server won't be affected becasue all it ever sees is the root just the same as if you had anchors on any normal web page

Comment: I understand how does the hash work, but I cannot understand why this case doesn't and have no idea where to look for a problem.

Comment: try turning off the url rewrites on server. Not clear what is actually happening but I doubt I could help there anyway

Comment: Are you sure that your script gets loaded into the page? can you confirm this?

Comment: Yes all, the coffeescripts are builded to single js file using grunt. And that file is loaded. Browser console doesn't throw any error, and even alerting at the beginning of each coffeescript works.

Comment: To be honest after so much time with dealing with it I am starting to have doubts if I turn on/off url rewrites on the server correctly. Does anyone could tell me how it should be done?